# $A$-module is also module over subring $B⊆A$ in general?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a ring and $M$ be $A$-module.
Suppose $B⊆A$ be a ring containing $1$.
Is $M$ can be regarded as $B$ module in general ?

I think this is true because we can restrict action by $A$ to $B$, but
my book reads $M$ is $B$module when we can say $B$ submodule of certain big module $M'$. This is why I'm confused.

Why can't we regard $M$ as $B$ module in general ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I think you are looking for that concept:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings

in more general language, if you consider modules to be functors from the Ring identified as a category with 1 object and endomorphisms given by the Ring your functor would just be composition with the inclusion, which of course is well behaved and gives you a new functor, which in this case would be a module again.
The other two change of rings functors are sadly not as straight forward.

Sorry for the categorical approach, but it makes everything far more natural to see!